# Iterating through a C++ vector with wrap-around

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have an assignment to iterate through a vector and erase every third number. If it hits the end of the vector, it should continue counting again from the first entry, until only one number remains. The user inputs how many numbers should be in the vector.

I'm having trouble getting used to the difference between vectors and arrays - just last week we had a problem that involved wrapping around an array, which was solved with mod, but I quickly figured out this wouldn't work for vectors.

Here was my idea so far: Iterate through and delete every third entry until the size of the vector is 1.

```
 while (vector.size > 1) {
            for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = suitors.begin(); i <= suitors.end(); i++) {
           // here, add a case for if it hits the end, start over
           if (i = suitors.end()) {
                   i = suitors.begin();
           }
           suitors.erase(suitors.at(i) + 2);
    }
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to have it start over, as spits out an error when I try to use i in this way.

Any advice or tips to get me on the right path here? I'm beginning to see how versatile vectors are, but they just aren't clicking yet. I'm also not sure if there is a better way to stop it from iterating besides the while loop.

Comment: if you erase every 3rd number until only one number remains, what do you do when there are only 2 numbers left in the vector?

Comment: The same as if it hits the end of the vector - it loops around and keeps counting. Basically, say there are 6 numbers. It should go like this:
123456
12456
1245
125
15
1

What I need to do is find what that last number will be for any starting value.

Comment: won't the end result always just be the first element in the vector?

Comment: you have 
`if ( i = suitors.end() )`
did you mean 
`if ( i == suitors.end() )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `remove_if` to move items in the vector to the end whenever an index variable that is incremented each time reaches 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6};

  unsigned index = 0;   // this is the index variable used to remove elements
  auto end = v.end();   // point to the current end of the vector

  // keep looping until there is only 1 element in the vector
  while(std::distance(v.begin(), end) > 1) {
    // remove_if will call the predicate for each element
    // the predicate simply increments the index each time, and when it reaches 
    // 3 indicates that element should be removed
    // remove_if will move items to the end of the vector and return an 
    // iterator to the end of the new range, so we'll update the end variable 
    // with the result
    end = std::remove_if(v.begin(), end, [&index](int) {
      if(++index == 3) {
        // reset the index and indicate this element should be removed
        return (index = 0), true;
      }
      return false;
    });

    for(auto iter = v.begin(); iter != end; ++iter) {
      std::cout << *iter << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }

  // erase all the elements we've removed so far
  v.erase(end, v.end());
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 4 5 
1 2 5 
1 5 
1
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81fbb82b781242f3)

Answer (score 0):

The outer while loop I'm assuming means to go as long as the vector has more than one element, but this should be included in the for, not another loop

The syntactic issue is in the if:

```
if (i = suitors.end())
   // ^ should be ==
```

otherwise you're just assigning end to your iterator

```
for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = suitors.begin(); suitors.size() > 1; ++i) {
                                                 // ^ loop condition changed
       if (i == suitors.end()) {
           i = suitors.begin();
       }
       suitors.erase(suitors.at(i) + 2);
}
```

modifying a container as you iterate through it is dangerous though..